# Python: for loop iterations when adding dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I have a dataframe with different returns looking something like:

```
0.2  -0.1  0.03  0.01
0.02  0.1  -0.1  -0.2
0.05  0.06  0.07 -0.07
0.03 -0.04 -0.04 -0.03
```

And I have a separate dataframe with the index returns in only one column:

```
0.01
0.015
-0.01
-0.02
```

What I want to do is to basically add(+) each row value of the index return dataframe with each value for each column in the stock return dataframe.

The desired outcome looks like:

```
0.21  -0.09
0.035  0.115
0.04   0.05
0.01  -0.06 etc etc
```

Normally in Matlab for example the for loop would be quite simple, but in python the indexing is what gets me stuck.
I have tried a simple for loop:

```
for i, j in df_stock_returns.iterrows():
    df_new = df_stock_returns[i, j] + df_index_reuturns[j]
```

But that doesn't really work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you make the latter a numpy array, you can add directly without alignment issues `df1 + df2.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
      0     1     2     3
0  0.20 -0.10  0.03  0.01
1  0.02  0.10 -0.10 -0.20
2  0.05  0.06  0.07 -0.07
3  0.03 -0.04 -0.04 -0.03
```

and

```
In [28]: dfi
Out[28]: 
       0
0  0.010
1  0.015
2 -0.010
3 -0.020
```

you can just write

```
In [26]: pd.concat([df[c] + dfi[0] for c in df], axis=1)
Out[26]: 
       0      0      1      2
0  0.210 -0.090  0.040  0.020
1  0.035  0.115 -0.085 -0.185
2  0.040  0.050  0.060 -0.080
3  0.010 -0.060 -0.060 -0.050
```

In pandas you almost never need to iterate over individual cells. Here I just iterated over the columns, and `df[c] + dfi[0]` adds the two columns element-wise. Then `concat` with `axis=1` (0=rows, 1=columns) just concatenates everything into one dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the most straightforward way will work

```
for c in a.columns:
    a[c] = a[c] + b

>>> a
       0      1      2      3
0  0.210 -0.090  0.040  0.020
1  0.215 -0.085  0.045  0.025
2  0.190 -0.110  0.020  0.000
3  0.180 -0.120  0.010 -0.010
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add two `df` as below

```
col1=[0.2,0.02]
col2=[-0.1,0.2]
col3=[0.01,0.015]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(col1, col2)),columns=['list1','list2'])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'list3':col3})

output = df1[:] + df2['list3'].values
```

The `df1[:]` extract all columns and it to the reference column `df2['list3']`